# Creating a custom drop down menu flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to create a custom drop down menu for my app, I have a picture of what it should look like. I have been searching online to see if there are any similar ideas, although everything I'm finding does not support null safety and so I am running into problems. If it comes down to it I will try and code my own drop down although if anyone could lead me in the right direction that would be great only because I'm new to flutter.

Also I have tried using DropdownButton in flutter but it does not produce what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use DropDown button class, here is a complete running code, you can run it in dartpad

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: _title,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
    body: const Center(
      child: MyStatefulWidget(),
     ),
   ),
 );
 }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
String dropdownValue = 'One';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownValue,
  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
  elevation: 16,
  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
  underline: Container(
    height: 2,
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue!;
    });
  },
  items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2).

Check out Example 3 of `How to add different height items like dividers` and check out `Options` to see all parameters you can use to customize DropdownButton2 to your design.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the package mentioned above.

Comment: I will look into this, this seems to be the best option so far unless I want to do a complete custom drop down, thank you.

Comment: I made the package to be completely customizable. It's core DropdownButton from flutter but with more features and more customizable. If you find something messing, open an issue and I'll try to add it.